# How do I Take everything in a collection using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a method which can accept an optional `int?` value as a number of items to `Take` from a collection. I want to **return all items if a null value is passed**. Right now I have to duplicate my query to accomplish this

```
if(take == null)
{
     x = db.WalkingDeadEps.Where(x => x.BicyclesCouldHaveSavedLives == true).ToList()
}
else
{
     x = db.WalkingDeadEps.Where(x => x.BicyclesCouldHaveSavedLives == true).Take(take).ToList()
}
```

Is there a simpler way? Something like this?

```
.Take(take != null ? take : "all")
```

Comment: i'm not sure what your asking ... surely just return db.WalkingDeadEps.Where(x => x.BicyclesCouldHaveSavedLives == true).ToList() ?

Comment: don't use == true; it's ugly. And BicyclesCouldHaveSavedLives = cool Property name

Comment: @Dennis_E thanks - why is == true ugly? What's the alternative?

Comment: `Where(x => x.BicyclesCouldHaveSavedLives)` or `Where(x => !x.BicyclesCouldHaveSavedLives)`

Comment: if its a `bool?` / nullable boolean, will this still work?

Comment: @roryok a boolean is already true or false. == true doesn't do anything. Just leave it out. So if(b) instead of if(b==true)

Comment: @roryok, if its nullable it will not work, because `Where()` requests an bool as return type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with Linq you have the option to store your query in variables. it will not be executed until you call `ToList` or equivalent methods on it.

```
var query = db.WalkingDeadEps.Where(x => x.BicyclesCouldHaveSavedLives == true);
x = take.HasValue ? query.Take(take.Value).ToList() : query.ToList();
```